# How to use results of one sql query within a sub-query

Tags: sql, subquery

I have to answer the following question

> "For each year in the database, list the year and the total number of
>   movies that were released in that year, showing these totals in
>   decreasing order. That is, the year(s) with the largest number of
>   movies appear first. If some years have the same number of movies,
>   show these in increasing order of year."

Currently I am using the code below to get the movies to group together, but am unable to get them to sort:

```
Select YearReleased, count(*)                
from Movies                             
group by YearReleased
```

I wish to use something to order this and  am trying to make a sub query that uses the results of the first query, along the lines of:

```
(select * from results order by count(*))
```

but so far I have been unsuccessful. How do I achieve this or is there a better way of getting the results in that order?

Comment: Instead of asking "I want to do $foo via method $bar, but if you know a better way, that's OK", it would probably be better to ask "I want to do $foo; I'm currently trying $bar, but it fails with method $baz; how *should* I do this?".

Answer (score 5):

"Unsuccessful" isn't very useful, as opposed to actual error text -- and you aren't telling us which vendor's database you're running against, so we can't test. That said, the following should work:

```
select
  YearReleased,
  count(*) as movie_count
  from movies
  group by YearReleased
  order by movie_count desc, YearReleased;
```

No subqueries needed!

Validated against SQLite 3.5.9; if running against something less standards-compliant (which SQLite *is*, except in very explicitly documented ways), your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

select *
from
(
Select YearReleased, count(*) as NumReleased
from Movies
group by YearReleased 
)
order by NumReleased

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select YearReleased, count(*) counter
from Movies
group by YearReleased 
) a order by counter
```

May need a syntax change depending on your sql flavour.

Answer (score 0):

in first query: select yearReleased, count(*) **as 'count1'**
in second: order by **count1**

Answer (score 0):

Yep, with aggregates you can just put an alias for count(*) and it can be reffered as a column.